# Pivot confuses me. Can someone help me understand using my example?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This is the query that I'm working with:

```
select
    p.person_nbr, 
    psm.description,
    m.medication_name,
    StartDate,
    endDate
from person p
    left join patient_medication m
        on p.person_id = m.person_id
    left join patient_status ps 
        on ps.person_id = p.person_id
    left join patient_status_mstr psm 
        on psm.patient_status_id = ps.patient_status_id
```

It retrieves this data:

```
person_nbr  description medication_name             StartDate   endDate
      47    Intake      Seroquel 300 mg tablet      07/13/2017  01/01/1900
      47    Active      Risperdal 1 mg tablet       10/21/2017  11/21/2017
      47    Active      sertraline 100 mg tablet    10/21/2017  11/21/2017
      271   Active      sertraline 100 mg tablet    11/21/2017  12/26/2017
      271   Active      Risperdal 1 mg tablet       11/21/2017  12/26/2017
```

I want to pivot the data into predefined columns. The goal is to have 10 total columns that data is added into. The m.medication_name field will pivot into a total of 5 columns using the naming convention of MedName1, MedName2, MedName3, MedName4, MedName5. The corresponding dates need to be similarly distributed (MedDate1, MedDate2, MedDate3, MedDate4, MedDate5). Ex:

[image: example of pivoted table]

I need to limit each partition (partitioned by person_nbr) to 5 total medications and date pairs. If there are more than 5, I need to disregard them.

I've tried messing around with pivot, but havent come close to getting it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Someone might have a good solution with pivot but you can rank with `ROW_NUMBER()` and then `from [row numbered rows] [med1] left join [row numbered rows] [med2...3...4...5] on patient id and row number = 2 ... 3 ... 4 ... 5 where [med1].row number = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use `PIVOT`. There's probably a more elegant way to do this but its maintainability is tractable for two attributes per patient and five or six medications.

Note that it's an example only, I was a bit loose with escaping identifiers with `[]` and the final output doesn't quite match yours (e.g. `MedDate1` is `2017-07-13` to your `7/13/2017` ... format your dates as you see fit).

```
DECLARE @PersonMedication TABLE
  (
     person_nbr      INT NOT NULL,
     [description]   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     medication_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     StartDate       DATE NOT NULL,
     EndDate         DATE NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO @PersonMedication
            (person_nbr, [description], medication_name, StartDate, EndDate)
/* End preceeds Start... */
VALUES      (47, 'Intake', 'Seroquel 300 mg tablet', '2017-07-13', '1900-01-01'),
            (47, 'Active', 'Risperdal 1 mg tablet', '2017-10-21', '2017-11-21'),
            (47, 'Active', 'sertraline 100 mg tablet', '2017-10-21', '2017-11-21'),
            (271, 'Active', 'sertraline 100 mg tablet', '2017-11-21', '2017-12-26'),
            (271, 'Active', 'Risperdal 1 mg tablet', '2017-11-21', '2017-12-26');

WITH ctePersonMedicationRowNumber
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY person_nbr
                    ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate) RowNumber,
                *
         FROM   @PersonMedication)
SELECT tmpPersonMedication1.person_nbr,
       /* Get the most recent description i.e. 5th is older than 4th is older than ... */
       COALESCE(tmpPersonMedication5.[description], tmpPersonMedication4.[description], tmpPersonMedication3.[description], tmpPersonMedication2.[description], tmpPersonMedication1.[description]) [description],
       tmpPersonMedication1.[medication_name]                                                                                                                                                       MedName1,
       tmpPersonMedication1.[StartDate]                                                                                                                                                             MedDate1,
       tmpPersonMedication2.[medication_name]                                                                                                                                                       MedName2,
       tmpPersonMedication2.[StartDate]                                                                                                                                                             MedDate2,
       tmpPersonMedication3.[medication_name]                                                                                                                                                       MedName3,
       tmpPersonMedication3.[StartDate]                                                                                                                                                             MedDate3,
       tmpPersonMedication4.[medication_name]                                                                                                                                                       MedName4,
       tmpPersonMedication4.[StartDate]                                                                                                                                                             MedDate4,
       tmpPersonMedication5.[medication_name]                                                                                                                                                       MedName5,
       tmpPersonMedication5.[StartDate]                                                                                                                                                             MedDate5
FROM   ctePersonMedicationRowNumber tmpPersonMedication1
       LEFT JOIN ctePersonMedicationRowNumber tmpPersonMedication2
              ON tmpPersonMedication1.person_nbr = tmpPersonMedication2.person_nbr
                 AND tmpPersonMedication2.RowNumber = 2
       LEFT JOIN ctePersonMedicationRowNumber tmpPersonMedication3
              ON tmpPersonMedication1.person_nbr = tmpPersonMedication3.person_nbr
                 AND tmpPersonMedication3.RowNumber = 3
       LEFT JOIN ctePersonMedicationRowNumber tmpPersonMedication4
              ON tmpPersonMedication1.person_nbr = tmpPersonMedication4.person_nbr
                 AND tmpPersonMedication4.RowNumber = 4
       LEFT JOIN ctePersonMedicationRowNumber tmpPersonMedication5
              ON tmpPersonMedication1.person_nbr = tmpPersonMedication5.person_nbr
                 AND tmpPersonMedication5.RowNumber = 5
WHERE  tmpPersonMedication1.RowNumber = 1;
```